# empty path name not legal

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

I have a "save" button so when users click, it will do a saving of xml file(xml serialization). A savefiledialog is used here and when i press cancel without selecting any file an "Argument Exception" occurs and says "Empty path name is not legal". How do i handle this exception? I would like the form to remain the same even without any path selected in the savefiledialog. Many thanks.

My savefiledialog snippet:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        string savepath;
        SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
        // Default file extension
        DialogSave.DefaultExt = "txt";
        // Available file extensions
        DialogSave.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        // Adds a extension if the user does not
        DialogSave.AddExtension = true;
        // Restores the selected directory, next time
        DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
        // Dialog title
        DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
        // Startup directory
        DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
        DialogSave.ShowDialog();
        savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
        DialogSave.Dispose();
        DialogSave = null;
        ...
        using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
        {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
                serializer.Serialize(savestream, formsaving);
        }

}
```

My argument exception occurs at this line:

```
using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
{
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
        serializer.Serialize(savestream, formsaving);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you do not care about the result of the Save dialog, and you try to save even if the user clicked Cancel. You should change the code to look something like this instead:

```
...
DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
if( DialogSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
{
  savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
  DialogSave = null;
  ...
  using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
  {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
     serializer.Serialize(savestream, formsaving);
  }
}
DialogSave.Dispose();
```

Comment: instead of calling `DialogSave.Dispose()` i would put it into a `using()` statement

Comment: @Oliver - I agree with you. I wrote my code to not make to much changes to the OPs code, but using on the SaveFileDialog at the start of the method would be the way to go.

Comment: i'm using wpf and there seems to be a problem with " DialogResult.OK " i get this error: 'System.Nullable<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'OK' and no extension method 'OK' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @jeremychan - I didn't see the WPF tag on your question. Sorry about that. In WPF you can simply check `if(DialogSave.ShowDialog() == true ){...`

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to save if the user cancels the dialog? Check for the result from `ShowDialog` and act accordingly:

```
if (DialogSave.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
            ...
    using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
        serializer.Serialize(savestream, formsaving);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi fredrik i get this error at the `if (DialogSave.ShowDialog() == true) ` Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' and 'bool'

Comment: @jeremychan: I guess I was fooled by the wpf tag and your comment on Øyvind's answer. The winforms dialog returns a `DialogResult`, the wpf counterpart returns a `Nullable<bool>`.